# How to request an available port to OS in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have many same programs and they run in different ports.

Configuring them manually is difficult so I want to apply for some available ports from OS.

But I can't find a way to implement this operation cuz I'm new to rust.

(Extra condition is that I have an external program have to know all ports of them so specifying the port to zero will can't achieve this)

Comment: This isn't a language problem. I'm not aware that any operating systems operate this kind of port management. The unreserved ports are generally first-come, first-serve, and it's your job to pick an unused one.

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

specify the port to zero let OS assign an available port for me and expose it by `SocketAddr` in Actix. (raw TCP in a similar way with `SocketAddrV4`)

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    
    set_var("PWNXY_CLIENT_PORT", "8080").unwrap();

    let srv = HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(hello)
            .service(echo)
            .route("/hey", web::get().to(manual_hello))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 0))?;

    println!("{:#?}", srv.addrs()[0].port());

    srv.run().await
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`bind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.bind):

> Binding with a port number of 0 will request that the OS assigns a port to this listener. The port allocated can be queried via the TcpListener::local_addr method.